# How to pad sequences during training for an encoder decoder model

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, sequence-modeling, language-model

I've got an encoder-decoder model for character level English language spelling correction, it is pretty basic stuff with a two LSTM encoder and another LSTM decoder.

However, up until now, I have been pre-padding the input sequences, like below:

```
abc  -> -abc
defg -> defg
ad   -> --ad
```

And next I have been splitting the data into several groups with the same output length, e.g.

```
train_data = {'15': [...], '16': [...], ...}
```

where the key is the length of the output data and I have been training the model once for each length in a loop.

However, there has to be a better way to do this, such as padding after the EOS character etc. But if this is the case, how would I change the loss function so that this padding isn't counted into the loss?